# Convert foreach to be part of LINQ query (C#)

Tags: c#

I currently have a LINQ query to get some JSON files and then I run a foreach loop to convert the JSON into an object. Ultimately I want to have a `List<Config>` which I can work from.

Is there any way I can combine this into the LINQ query so I've just got the one statement, and files is of type `List<Config>`?

```
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(PATH, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.Contains(CONFIG_NAME));
            List<Config> lc = new List<Config>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Config config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(File.ReadAllText(file));
                lc.add(config);
            }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Provide more sensible code: currently you're having a variable scoped in a loop that is not visible outside of it. So your code is naturally no-op.

Comment: Then `Enumerable.Select()` is what you need

Comment: I've added the `lc.add()` to give a better idea. Basically I want to be able to put this whole thing in one LINQ query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var configs = 
    Directory
    .GetFiles(PATH, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.Contains(CONFIG_NAME))
    .Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(File.ReadAllText(x)));
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. (I also added .ToList() to be able to explicitly type configs)

Comment: The current result should be typed `IEnumerable<Config>`

Answer (score 1):

[.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method of `List<T>`.  As a result, you need to call `.ToList()` on your predicate before you can call `.ForEach()` since currently you are returning a projection, not an actual list.

That said, this doesn't actually give you what you want, because `.ForEach()` returns void.  You want [.Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
var configs = Directory.GetFiles(PATH, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(s => s.Contains(CONFIG_NAME))
                .Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(x.ReadAllText(x)))
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think something along the lines of this would work:

```
var result = (from f 
              in Directory.GetFiles(PATH, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              where f.Contains(CONFIG_NAME)
              select JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(File.ReadAllText(f)) ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .Select() method ([Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx))

So your code would be:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(PATH, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.Contains(CONFIG_NAME));
var configs = files.Select(f => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(File.ReadAllText(f)));
```

OR in one line

```
var configs = Directory.GetFiles(PATH, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.Contains(CONFIG_NAME)).Select(f => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(File.ReadAllText(f)));
```